# Roslyn exception on deployed machine

Tags: c#, exception, roslyn

I have developed a console app using Roslyn (CTP Sept 2012). It is working perfectly in my box. However the same app not working in the deployed machine. It is throwing the following error.

> *The type initializer for
>   'Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.InternalSyntax.LexerCache' threw an
>   exception.*

I have checked if the client box had 4.5 installed as well. Any help in this pls.

Comment: WHat's the inner exception?

Comment: There was no inner exception. However, after reinstalling the V4.5 on deployed machine, this issue not reproducing.